# Get list of distinct keys and count of nodes that have them

Tags: cypher

Using a `cypher` query, I can get a list of keys for a type of node:

```
MATCH (n:Category) RETURN keys(n);
```

The result:

```
 ╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
 │"keys(n)"                                                      │
 ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
 │["CreatedDate","Category","_lastModified","_x","_y","_created"]│
 ├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
 │["CreatedDate","_lastModified","_x","_y","_created","Category"]│
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

In the above example, there are only two nodes, and they have the same keys.  Sometimes there's a lot of nodes, and they don't all have the same keys.

How can I return an aggregate of the keys and the count of nodes that have that key?

In this case the result would be:

```
2 CreatedDate
2 Category
2 _lastModified
2 _x
2 _y
2 _created
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some basic sample data:

```
MERGE (c1: Category { name: 'A', OnlyA: 'ValueOnlyA', Both: 'ValueBoth' })
MERGE (c2: Category { name: 'B', OnlyB: 'ValueOnlyB', Both: 'AnotherValueBoth' } )
```

You can get the set of property keys seen on any of the nodes in the set, and the number of times they were seen:

```
MATCH (c: Category)
UNWIND keys(c) as k
RETURN k, count(k)
```

```
╒═══════╤══════════╕
│"k"    │"count(k)"│
╞═══════╪══════════╡
│"Both" │2         │
├───────┼──────────┤
│"name" │2         │
├───────┼──────────┤
│"OnlyA"│1         │
├───────┼──────────┤
│"OnlyB"│1         │
└───────┴──────────┘
```